# How can I browse the functions and methods of a script using Chrome developer tools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I have imported a JavaScript file into a web page.

I want to browse (not search) the methods and functions loaded.

How can I do that?

Comment: You should be able to see this in the Sources tab.  Another way is to use the Network tab, filter to JS and the choose the JS file you are interested in.

Comment: I think `ctrl+space` in the console is as close as you'll come. Sure, chrome shows lots of stuff that is irrelevant to your script. But as long as you know the namespace-object it can work wonders. `$.<ctrl-space>` gives a pretty exhaustive list of jquery methods for example.  I think the problem of creating what you describe lies in how dynamic JavaScript is. Every function/object can be mutated by some other script. But I don't disagree with you. At least some grouping of what function/object comes from what script would be nice.